# How can I use i18n in a combobox using struts2?

Tags: forms, jsp, internationalization, combobox, struts2

I have a form with a combobox to allow people select if they are a male or female. I want to change *Male* and *Female* for the same words in other language.

My actual combobox is:

```
<s:combobox readonly="true" key="sex" 
list="{'Male', 'Female'}" value="Male" />
```

Is there a way to put this combobox in different languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. I have to implement an action that shows this jsp page with a list in its attributes and a getter.

```
public class Action extends ActionSupport {
    ...
    private List<String> genders = new ArrayList<String> ();

    public Action ()
    {
        genders.add(getText("male"));
        genders.add(getText("female"));
    }

    @Override
    public String input() throws Exception {    
        return NONE;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then in the jsp page, I use this attribute as the list needed in the combobox.

```
<s:combobox readonly="true" key="generos" list="genders"/>
```